# Отправка сообщений телеграмм бота в определенное время

Tags: python, datetime, telebot

Задача заключается в отправки сообщений в определенное время без встречного сообщения.
Пытаюсь написать код (использую pyTelegramBotAPI 4.2.2), который в заданное время (например, 12 часов дня) должен отправить определенное сообщение в группу. Проблема заключается в том, что без встречного сообщения, отправленного пользователем, бот ничего не может отправить, а нужно чтобы несмотря на встречное сообщение и другие факторы отправлял сообщение в назначенное время. Помогите пожалуйста написать код

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

bot = telebot.TeleBot( "TOKEN" , parse_mode = None)

BOT_URL = "URL"
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    

bot.infinity_polling()
```

---

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot( "" , parse_mode = None)
BOT_URL = "URL"
otv = "123"
now = datetime.now() 
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

#Запускаем цикл для проверки времени
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if current_time == '19:40':#Выставляете ваше время
        print('pass')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, otv)
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Что здесь неправильно?

Answer (score -1):

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message : types.Message):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if current_time == '23:44:01': 
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'"Это сообщение отправлено в {current_time}"')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['mess'])
async def command(message : types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Для полной картины, асинхронность работает')

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Ну как то так я это решил, уж не знаю на столько это плохой тон.

Answer (score -2):

если вам такое подойдет, то вот:

```
import telebot
import time
from datetime import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot( "TOKEN" , parse_mode = None)
BOT_URL = "URL"

now = datetime.now() 
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

#Запускаем цикл для проверки времени
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if current_time == '12:00':#Выставляете ваше время
        print('pass')
        bot.send_message("тут айди вашей группы", 'text')
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

надеюсь смог вам помочь

Comment: это учитывая что бот будет только для этого, потому-что если туда добавить другие команды как в боте, они не будут работать из-за "while True"

Comment: Насколько я понимаю это единственный способ решить данную проблему. Конечно, в задачи бота должны были входить и ответы на встречные сообщения, но ничего не мешает создать ещё одного бота, тк как все рассчитывается именно на группу в телеграмм

Comment: ну есть еще вариант создать отдельным файлом это, и рядом создать самого бота, тоесть токен будет 1, но он будет делать и то, и то

Comment: То есть создать два файла, чтобы каждый отвечал за свою команду, и они смогут работать параллельно?

Comment: то-есть создать 2 файла, в 1 этот код из проверкой кода, в другом сам бот, и так как и там, и там 1 токен, то это будет делать 1 бот, а что бы они это все делали параллельно, могу вам посоветовать библиотеку asyncio

Comment: Может я что-то делаю не так, можете меня пожалуйста поправить. Почему то бот никак не реагирует на время

Comment: а в чем-то ошибка есть? или просто 0 реакции?